# After configure an .sh with chkconfig, systemctl says unit myservice not found

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, chkconfig

I'm doing some labs for test setups... I've developed a bash script to set it to autostart using systemd.

I installed chkconfig and configured my script as follows:

Using root:

```
cd /mypath
cp myscript.sh /etc/init.d/
cd /etc/init.d

chkconfig --add myscript.sh
chkconfig myscript.sh on

systemctl start myscript
```

I'm receiving:

```
Unit myscript.service could not be found.
```

Comment: WHat is the content of this script?

Comment: Basically is the same script used to start jboss in standalone... comes with jboss installer in JBOSS_HOME/bin/init.d

Comment: Have you try to run it like this: `service myscript start`?

Comment: Yes, I did that with the same result

Comment: Check with `chkconfig --list` if the script is added and what is the name of this service and then use it in `service <name> start`

Comment: I did that and I see my service there but when I use `service myscript start` shows `Unit myscript.service could not be found.`

`# chkconfig --list
myscript.sh     0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off`

Comment: What about `systemctl start myscript.sh` or `service myscript.sh start`?

Comment: @GracefulRestart Yes, I tested that and did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I see that after any changes to /etc/init.d/ I need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` to apply the changes, after that I was able to use `systemctl start myscript.services`

Thank you all for your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can consider using native `systemd` script to start JBoss. [Here](https://gist.github.com/spuk-/1cbe5865363a3217d39ff890fa9ee763) you can find a example one. Feel free to change the paths and variables to reflect your installation.

```
[Unit]
Description=Jboss Application Server
After=syslog.target network.target ypbind.service

[Service]
Type=simple
TimeoutSec=0
User=jboss
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/jboss-standalone.conf
StandardOutput=journal
ExecStart=/bin/java \
    -D"[Standalone]" \
    -server \
    $GC_LOG_ROTATE \
    -Djboss.server.log.dir=${JBOSS_LOG_DIR} \
    $JAVA_OPTS \
    -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=${JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS} \
    -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=${JBOSS_LOG_DIR}/server.log \
    -Dlogging.configuration=${JBOSS_LOG_CONF} \
    -jar ${JBOSS_HOME}/jboss-modules.jar \
    $MODULE_OPTS \
    -mp ${JBOSS_MODULEPATH} \
    org.jboss.as.standalone \
    -Djboss.home.dir=${JBOSS_HOME} \
    -Djboss.server.base.dir=${JBOSS_BASE_DIR} \
    $SERVER_OPTS

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As starting point you can use this JBoss config for above script:

```
JBOSS_BASE_DIR=/opt/jboss/standalone
JBOSS_LOG_DIR=/opt/jboss/standalone/log
JBOSS_LOG_CONF=file:/opt/jboss/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
JBOSS_MODULEPATH=/opt/jboss/modules
JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS=org.jboss.byteman
JAVA_OPTS= \
    -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MetaspaceSize=512M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m \
    -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
    -Djava.awt.headless=true
SERVER_OPTS=-c standalone.xml

#MODULE_OPTS="-secmgr"
#DEBUG_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
#GC_LOG_ROTATE=-verbose:gc \
    -Xloggc:/opt/jboss/standalone/log/gc.log \
    -XX:+PrintGCDetails \
    -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps \
    -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation \
    -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 \
    -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M \
    -XX:-TraceClassUnloading
```